# Getting item current balance using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I get certain item balance in certain store from below schema ?

```
item balance = ItemOpeningBalances.OpeiningBalance + PurchaseOrderDetails.ReceivedQuantity
```

I have tried to get balance using below query but it gave me `null` value in balance

**Query**

```
SELECT
    i.ItemID,
    s.StoreID,
    SUM(iob.OpeiningBalance + pod.ReceivedQuantity) AS balance
FROM  
    dbo.StoreDetails st
LEFT JOIN 
    Stores s ON st.StoreID = s.StoreID
LEFT JOIN 
    PurchaseOrders po ON st.PurchaseOrderID = po.PurchaseOrderID
LEFT JOIN 
    PurchaseOrderDetails pod ON po.PurchaseOrderID = pod.PurchaseOrderID
LEFT JOIN 
    Items i ON pod.ItemID = i.ItemID
LEFT JOIN 
    ItemOpeningBalances iob ON st.OpeiningBalanceID = iob.OpeiningBalanceID
                            AND i.ItemID = iob.ItemID
WHERE 
    (i.ItemID = 1)
    AND (s.StoreID = 1)
GROUP BY 
    i.ItemID, s.StoreID
```

**Output**

```
ItemID StoreID balance
1      1       Null
```

**Schema**

[image]

Comment: Instead of a picture of your tables it would be better if you posted ddl and sample data in a consumable format. This article does a great of explaining how to do this. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

This may be happening because anything plus `null` is `null`.

Try this:

```
SELECT
  i.ItemID,
  s.StoreID,
  SUM(COALESCE(iob.OpeiningBalance,0) + COALESCE(pod.ReceivedQuantity,0) AS balance
FROM dbo.StoreDetails st
LEFT JOIN Stores s
  ON st.StoreID = s.StoreID
LEFT JOIN PurchaseOrders po
  ON st.PurchaseOrderID = po.PurchaseOrderID
LEFT JOIN PurchaseOrderDetails pod
  ON po.PurchaseOrderID = pod.PurchaseOrderID
LEFT JOIN Items i
  ON pod.ItemID = i.ItemID
LEFT JOIN ItemOpeningBalances iob
  ON st.OpeiningBalanceID = iob.OpeiningBalanceID
  AND i.ItemID = iob.ItemID
WHERE (i.ItemID = 1)
AND (s.StoreID = 1)
GROUP BY i.ItemID,
         s.StoreID
```

Comment: @Ayman perhaps you could explain what the problem is. Just saying it doesn't give the sum is not very helpful.

Comment: Item 1 has OpeiningBalance of 10 and ReceivedQuantity of 10 the sum sould be 20 but the query returns 10 as result maybe one of these columns returns null?